# What is the meaning of scene description ?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2562232/synopsis)

> Sam takes Riggan to costuming where he strips naked in front of her.
>   Lesley comes in, doesn't realize Sam is behind a rack of clothes and
>   tells Mike to put on clothes because Sam might come back and he
>   shouldn't be naked in front of Riggan's drug addict degenerate loser
>   daughter.

What I understand is: Actually Sam takes Riggan to costuming then here Sam might come back means what?

This description really confuses me.

Comment: Sam is there, but Lesley doesn't know that. So Lesley thinks Sam might come back.

Comment: 'Sam might come back' = 'It is possible that Sam will  come back'.

Comment: It also means that the scene description, indeed, the whole plot summary is poorly written. The quality of writing you are going to find on IMDB is apt to be even worse than on other places where anybody can write anything...even worse than places that can be easily edited by others. Not that many people edit IMDB articles, as compared to Wikipedia articles, but on the latter you will encounter poor/unclear writing quite often.

Answer (score 1):

Sam is a woman.  Sam is standing behind a rack of clothes. When Lesley enters the room, she **does not** see Sam because Sam is hidden by the rack of clothes. Therefore, Lesley does not think that Sam is in the room. That is what is meant by

> Lesley comes in, doesn't realize Sam is behind a rack of clothes

So when Lesley says Sam "might come back", from Lesley's perspective it is possible that Sam might return to the room because Lesley thinks Sam is outside of the room. The reality is that Sam is also in the room, hidden behind the rack of clothes.